# How user is logged in after registeration automatically in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am working on Auth and used Php artisan ui auth. Everything is setup but I can't understand the process.
When user is registering he is taken to **trait RegistersUsers**
Inside this trait they are taken to

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        if ($response = $this->registered($request, $user)) {
            return $response;
        }

        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new JsonResponse([], 201)
                    : redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
```

and what I have understood is that they are logged in via this line in **register** function above

```
 $this->guard()->login($user);
```

So I went to check its definition which lead me to **StatefulGuard.php** file and inside it there was

```
public function login(Authenticatable $user, $remember = false);
```

which I assume did the login part and logged the user into application
but thing that isn't clear to me is that where is definition or where is the above **login** function defined as I am unable to find it and at first I thought it is using **login** function of **trait AuthenticatesUsers** but it isn't as I placed dd inside login function in **trait AuthenticatesUsers** but it didn't worked.

So is there a separate login function that registration uses ?
and where is the function defined that I mentioned that is in **StatefulGuard.php**?

Answer (score 0):

use can log in using the below line also

Auth::login($user);
this is Auth Facade of laravel

Answer (score -1):

You can use laravel/ui package or you can get the logged in user after registration like the following.

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));
    $this->guard()->login($user);

    Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);

    if ($response = $this->registered($request, $user)) {
        return $response;
    }

    return $request->wantsJson()
        ? new JsonResponse([], 201)
        : redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```